# iOS, fast way to generate clickable, multicoloured text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to generate a text container that contains something like this:

This is **some** random text
where a **few** of the words are
**coloured** and **clickable**

The clickable words should have different actions bound to them and should be in a certain colour. The container will have a fixed width and I need to know the resulting height of the container given a certain text.

What I've tried: Tried making each word a separate UILabel, added actions where actions were needed, calculated line breaks myself. The problem with this approach was that it was too slow, especially UILabel sizeThatFits. I need to generate a lot of text for a scrolling UITableView and this approach killed the scrolling performance.

What I also tried: UIWebView. For a few different reasons, it's just not an option.

What I would prefer: A solution that does not require third party code. This is optional, though if they are open source. iOS 7-only solutions are acceptable.

Lastly, what needs to be fast is the generation of the text and the measuring of its height. Determining where to click is allowed to take some time.

Comment: UITextView in iOS 7 can do that. Explore UITextView

Comment: Do you have some examples on how UITextView can detect clicks on certain letters/words?

Comment: I don't have at the moment. I watched a presentation about the TextKit in iOS7 and I know it from there. I just wanted to forward you in right direction

Comment: Thank you, I will look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

See that https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel
..but i not understood about height

Answer (score 0):

If iOS only is an option, watch the WWDC 2013 session 210 "Introducing Text Kit". They show things that are at least very similar to what you are asking for.